# Python Flask not reading text in log.txt

Tags: python, flask, localhost

I have A flask app and A `log.txt` file so I want to extract the text, I used

```
import flask as f
app = f(__name__)
text = open('log.txt').read()
@app.route('\')
def index():
 return text
app.run()
```

in my log.txt

```
Hello World
```

Working perfectly but when I change the text in log.txt **Hello World** to **Hello Buddy**
Now go to `127.0.0.1:5000`

```
Hello World
```

Text in the browser is still **Hello World** How to change text without Restarting Flask App

Answer (score 4):

Put the line

```
text = open('log.txt').read()
```

inside (under) the def index(): method declaration.

Right now, the app reads the file ***only once*** (at startup) and serves that same data every time regardless of what the current contents of log.txt are.

To serve the latest copy of log.txt, it should be opened ***every time*** the method is called and not just at beginning of Flask app start

```
def index():
    text = open('log.txt').read()
    return text
```